# Why is the child of constraint acing up?

Tags: constraints

How can I get my child of constraint to work properly? I want this bullet to be in the revolver's chamber but when I clear the set the inverse it goes haywire.

EDIT

I'm still stuck, I really hope someone can help me so I can move on with my project. I can offset the child of by moving the object after adding the constraint, but then it freaks it again when I clear set inverse.

[image]

Comment: No one knows how to fix this?

Comment: [Posting the .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) would help us to understand what's going on. My first thought is: What are the three dotted lines? One must be the Child Of constraint, but what about the other two? Maybe it's parented to some other object and this is causing a conflict? Without being able to examine the file it's really hard to say.